# How do I share methods with instance variables in a superclass?

Tags: java

I have an abstract class called Car. Then I have two subclasses, Ford and Dodge which both extend Car. Each of these subclasses have a method called move(). The code in this method is identical for Ford and Dodge, so naturally my instinct was to throw this method implementation into the Car superclass so I don't have to have the same code twice in both my subclasses, i.e. get duplicated code, and just have this method written out once in code inside the superclass, and each subclass can call it when it needs to.

Now here's my...thing: Inside the move methods in each subclass, instance variables from each subclass are being manipulated. So you see, even though the code is identical, what is happening in each move()-method is depending on the state of that specific subclass's instance variables. Like this:

```
abstract class Car {

  // I want to put move()-method in here and erase it from subclasses
}


class Ford extends Car {

    private int rpm;

    public void move(){

    dosomestuff + rpm // value of rpm being used here is unique to Ford

     }
}

 class Dodge extends Car {

    private int rpm;

    public void move(){

    dosomestuff + rpm // value of rpm being used here is unique to Dodge

     }
}
```

I want to have it like this, and call move() in the superclass from each subclass using the subclasses instance variables:

```
abstract class Car {

  move(){
    // do stuff that is identical to Ford and Dodge but
    //  dependent on different instance variables
    }
}


class Ford extends Car {

    private int rpm;
}

 class Dodge extends Car {

    private int rpm;

}
```

Should I create variables inside the superclass Car? But that is what I am having problem wrapping my head around, because I know an abstract class cannot be instantiated! So if I were to pass the rpm-variable in this case as a parameter in the move() method like move(rpm), while I am having the implementation for move() only inside the Car class, I would have to return the rpm-variable to get its manipulated value back. This works, for once instance variable form a subclass. The problem is, the move-methods depend on several different kinds of variables. So I would have to return several variables back to the subclass each time but I am not sure how to do that.

I am confused. How can I condense this "duplicated code" inside my subclasses into the superclass Car and still be able to manipulate instance variables from the different subclasses inheriting from the Car class? Do I pass them as parameters and return them? Do I do something with get-set methods? I am so unsure...

Comment: first of, don´t shadow the `rpm` variable by declaring it multiple times in the inheritance chain. Just declare it in `Car` and use getter and setter and the constructors to set the variable. Your `move` method can simply use the getter method to get the value afterwards.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your problem right, but from what I understood, two approaches came into my mind: a) give your super-class `Car` the attribute `rpm`, as well as the implementation of `move()`. If this should not be possible (maybe you have some `Car`s, that move in a different way), you could either have a sub-class of `Car`, which is also a common super-class of `Ford` and `Dodge` or - if this is not acceptible, write it as an interface. If your `move`-methods, however, have different retunr-values, you are out of luck. This cannot (easily) be done with inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, but if I declare it once in Car, and car is abstract, the class can't be instantiated, so I cant have different values for rpm for Ford and Dodge right? Or how I do that? Do I have rpm-variable both in Car and in each subclass?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard that´s not how inheritance works. Yes you can´t instantiate the `Car` class itself, but every subclass of `Car` inherits it´s instance methods and instance variables. Though you just need to declare `rpm` once and access it in the subclasses like provided in the answer.

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard abstract means that you cannot instantiate the class directly, i.e. `... = new Car(...);` will result in a compiler error. If you have a class that `extends Car` and implements all methods (e.g. `Dodge`), the `Car` object is (implicitly) constructed, when the `Dodge` is constructed. Therefore, all fields within the `Car`-object are initialized. It is, as if they were defined within the child-class (provided they are `public` or `protected`).

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks. So am I right in saying that this means if I change the value of a variable in a superclass through a subclass, that change will not have happened for any other subclass inheriting from the superclass?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard yes, each instance has its own copy of this field/attribute and therefore an own value stored in this field/attribute.

Comment: @Turing85 Okay, then the only thing I don't get is the significance of the scope of the variable. If making the variable in Car protected means both subclasses can access it, but, as you say, still means each subclass manipulates a copy of that variable and not the actual variable, why is the compiler complaining if I set rpm to private then? You say that you don't actually edit that rpm variable in the Car class but a copy of it. So why does it want to "see" the variable in the superclass? To copy it or what?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard for the visibility check out [this tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). TL;DR: `protected` means "only the class itself, derived classes and classes in the same package can access this attribute/method".

Answer (score 7):

**Use `protected` variables**

```
abstract class Car {
  protected int rpm;
  move(){

    // ACCESS RPM HERE, which would be specific to implementing class
    }
}


class Ford extends Car {
}

 class Dodge extends Car {
}
```

Since the variable `rpm` is now protected, it will be accessible to the sub-classes of `Car` and when you instantiate `Ford` or `Dodge`, it would have it's own `rpm` value.

Makes sense?

Comment: An even "cleaner" approach would be to set `rpm` `private` and wrap it wiith accessor-methods. Those can then be set to the desired visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am probably retarded, but I am still not understanding how the subclasses get to have their own value of rpm. Surely protected int rpm in Car has only one value at a time since you can't instantiate Car? I mean, if I through say Ford change the value of rpm, doesn't this mean the value has also changed for Dodge since I am using the "same instance" of Car and both are using protected int rpm inside Car?

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard that´s why they are different instances which you are creating with `new X()`. Imagine it in the realy world. i´ve got two cars, two instances in the programming world, if i change the tires on my `Ford`, will the tires on my `Dodge` magicly change aswell? No, because each instance hold it´s own "values". And that´s what the `rpm` in the `Car` class does represent aswell. It says that each car has a `rpm`, but each individual car can have a differnt one.

Comment: @Kevin Esche so you mean each subclass has its own version of the Car-class? I thought this doesn't happen since Car can't be instantiated.

Comment: @OfeliavanAnalhard when you create an instance of `Ford` you get every accessible thing inside the `Car` class in your `Ford` object. So if you have a protected variable `int rpm` in `Car`, you will get your own `rpm` variable in your `Ford` as well, even without declaring it, that's why it's called inheritance, isn't?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara yes but isn't that the same instance of rpm in Car I am changing then inside the subclasses? or is it copied into each subclass somehow? I understand that the subclasses "see" the rpm variable in Car, but I don't understand if they are seeing the same rpm or not, meaning whether changing rpm in Car through Ford will change it for Dodge or not.

Comment: In simplest or non-technical terms for understanding/simplicity, there are copied to subclasses

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara Side note: I would at least mention that making **fields** available it not the ideal solution in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this answers your questions but sub classes inherit the methods of super classes so I would put everything in the abstract class and use getter setter (or access-mutate) methods to use all the variables in the abstract class.  I notice someone has stated protected variables which will work sometimes but not if you need encapsulation within your package.  I would do this:

```
public abstract class Car{
private int rpm;
public int getRPM(){return rpm;}
public void move(){//do move using getRPM() to access the data}

}
class Ford extends Car {
}

class Dodge extends Car {
}
```

So then the only thing different between Ford and Doge will be the constructor which is often times good when you are subclassing

Answer (score 0):

As others have written, you can pull your instance variables into your base class; and make them either protected; or provide getters for them; but honestly, I think that most likely will lead to a **bad** design.

The thing is: inheritance should be used to provide **behavior** to its subclasses, not **variables**.

Meaning: you consider carefully what kind of behavior you want to "share"; and then you think about the [open closed principle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-Closed-Prinzip) to implement it the right way, like:

```
abstract class Base {

  public final void doTheCommonThing() {
    System.out.println("but we need subclass stuff: " + getFromSubclass());
  }

  protected abstract String getFromSubclass();
}
```

The whole point of data encapsulation is that your base class **should not know** about variables in child classes; and vice versa. Because those are implementation details that nobody else has a business knowing about.

Comment: So you are saying to have duplicated attributes in each subclasses, i.e. declare the same instance variable rpm in both Ford and Dodge, and not in Car?

Comment: No. I am saying that you do **not** share attributes/fields. Because that is smell of bad design. The thing that you **share** are methods, not fields.

Comment: But in this case that means I should not share fields rpm, right? So then I would have to declare it in each of the subclasses.

Comment: I told you: in your case, you implement "move" on the base class; and "move" calls a method that fetches the values it needs using some protected method (that is or is not abstract). Again: the goal is a clean design; that doesn't violate the open/closed and data encapsulation principles.